# Possible to pick and choose which Managed Metadata Columns show in the Refinement Panel?

Tags: search, managed-metadata, refinement-panel

I am able to get all Managed Metadata Columns to show up by adding this to my `Filter Category Definition`:

```
<Category    Title="Managed Metadata Columns"    
             Description="Managed metadata of the documents"                 
             Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.TaxonomyFilterGenerator"
             MetadataThreshold="3"
             NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="3"
             MaxNumberOfFilters="20"
             ShowMoreLink="True"
             MappedProperty="ows_MetadataFacetInfo"
             MoreLinkText="show more"
             LessLinkText="show fewer" />
```

The problem is that it shows all Managed Metadata columns in whatever order it wants.  Is there a way for me to show only the columns I want and in the order I want in my refinement panel?

Comment: I've a couple of questions on this: (1) In the example, you've used "spshjobtitle" as the property you want to explicity include. But I cannot find an entry with this name in my Managed Metadata - indeed, this field is entitled "Job Title" in there. So how do I get the actual names I would need to use?
(2) What I actually want to "explicity" include is teh "Ask Me About" column. Whats that called?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `Title` attribute value to the name of the field you'd like to display (**spshjobtitle** in the example below). Any managed properties explicitly listed this way aren't going to be included again in the generic `Managed Metadata Columns` category.

```
<Category   Title="spshjobtitle"    
        Description="Use this filter to restrict results to a specific job title"    
        Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.TaxonomyFilterGenerator"    
        MetadataThreshold="3"    
        NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="3"    
        MaxNumberOfFilters="50"        
        ShowMoreLink="True"    
        MappedProperty="ows_MetadataFacetInfo"    
        MoreLinkText="show more"        
        LessLinkText="show fewer"/>
```

Refer to the [Category [Refinement]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625183.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: To clarify: "You can set the Title attribute value to the name of a _Managed Property corresponding to a field_ you'd like to display."  See 'Metadata Properties' in your search service app for a list of them.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Vassili Altynikov's answer, if your site column name contains a space, replace the space with **`"x0020"`** (not `"_x0020_"`). Don't ask me why it was implemented this way, since most other places in SharePoint, spaces become `"_x0020_"`, not `"x0020"`.

See here:
http://underthehood.ironworks.com/2011/05/sharepoint-2010-choose-your-managed-metadata-search-refinements.html